# Using Jimp Composite to overlap two images

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm really a beginner at this and have tried to get my code below to work for days.

I used a QR code generator library that allows me to include a logo in the middle of the qr code. After achieving this, I'm trying to add this qrcode on top of my background image. I intend to use the jimp composite function for this. After combining both images, I wish to return a buffer of the combined image.

```
app.get('/qr', (req, res) => {
  var url = "https://google.com";
  brandedQRCode.generate({
      text: url,
      path: __dirname +'/image/logo.png',
      ratio: 5.2,
      opt: {width: 500 , margin: 0}
    })
    .then(img => {

      var background = '/image/background.png';

      Jimp.read(img, function(){

        // Center the logo
        x = Math.floor((bg.bitmap.width - img.bitmap.width) / 2);
        y = Math.floor((bg.bitmap.height - img.bitmap.height) / 2);

        // Apply on the QRCode
        qrImg = bg.composite(img, x, y);
        new Promise(function (res, rej) {
          qrImg.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_PNG, function (err, buf) {
            if (err) return rej(err);
            return res(buf);
          });
        });
      });
      return Jimp.read(img);
    })
    .then(image => {
      image.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_PNG, (err, img) => {
        if (err) return rej(err);
        res.writeHead(200, {
           'Content-Type': 'image/png',
           'Content-Length': img.length
         });
        res.end(img);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
```

This code gives me an error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined"

Can anyone help me please, thank you so much!